# Django Query. Correct use of objects.select_related()

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have this models:

```
A = class(models.Model):
    onefield = ...

B = class(models.Model):
    property = models.CharField(...)
    foreign = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

So, I want to get all the objects A that are ForeignKeys of objects B with `property = x`.

I tried this:

```
query = B.objects.filter(property=x).select_related('A')
```

But it doesn't work. Is it possible to do this with `select_related()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I hesitate to contradict the illustrious Alex, and he's technically correct (the best kind of correct, after all), `select_related` is not the answer here. Using that never gives you different objects as a result; it only improves the efficiency of subsequently accessing related objects.

To get As, you need to start your query from A. You can use the double-underscore syntax to filter on the related property. So:

```
query = A.objects.filter(b__property=x)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to write `.select_related('foreign')`. `select_related` takes a field name, not a class name.